# Undefined Index in php When using ajax to POST from Apache Cordova App

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am trying to POST a number of variables using POST method in a jQuery ajax request. I am using a localhost sever as the receiver. Three of the variables are easily posted but the forth one isn't.

Here is the AJAX code -

```
var lat = ""+position.coords.latitude;
.
.// Some more code here for verifications
.
.
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
var dtls = document.getElementById("dtls").value;
dtls = dtls.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: server + 'record.php',
    data: {
         'email': email,
         'title': title,
         'dtls': encodeURIComponent(dtls), // These three get posted
         'latt': lat                 // This Variable isn't posted       
           /* There were 2 more here and even they weren't getting posted */
          },
          success: function (reply) {
                  flag = true;
                  doneLoading();
                  popUp(reply);
                  if (reply.endsWith("</body>")) {
                           var start = reply.indexOf("<h2>Id: ") + 8;
                           var len = reply.indexOf("</h2>") - start;
                           var id = reply.substr(start, len);
                           if (image != null) {
                                    uploadPhoto(image, id);
                           }
                   }
           },
           error: function (request, status, error) {
                   popUp("Error: " + error);
                   doneLoading();
                   flag = true;
           }
     });
```

Here is the php script -

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $server = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $password = "xyz";
        $db = "complaints";

        $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $db);

        $_POST['dtls'] = urldecode($_POST['dtls']);
        nl2br($_POST['dtls']);

        if($conn->connect_error)
        {
            die("Error: ".$conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO complaints (email, title, details, lat, longitude, time) VALUES ('".$_POST['email']."', \"".$_POST['title']."\", \"".$_POST['dtls']."\",".$_POST['latt'].",0,0)";

        if($conn->query($sql))
        {
            $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
            echo "<h2>Id: ".$last_id."</h2><h1>Success!! Your complaint has been successfully registered!!</h1></body>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<h1>Oops!! You are on the wrong page - This  Page is for POST purpose for the citizen forum app.</h1>";
    }
?>
```

I am sending the AJAX request through an Apache Cordova App.

The result of the request is this-

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: latt in E:\wamp3\www\record.php on line 25
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  135096  {main}( )   ...\record.php:0
Error: INSERT INTO complaints (email, title, details, lat, longitude, time) VALUES ('aneeshsharma15@outlook.com', "The street lights in our area are damaged", "The street lights in our area are damagedThe street lights in our area are damagedThe street lights in our area are damagedThe street lights in our area are damaged",,0,0)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0,0)' at line 1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does your console give you any errors?

Comment: No it doesn't show any errors

Comment: In your JS, what is `console.log(lat);`?

Comment: It show a number 43.465187 (the latitude of location)